# How to fix python int too large to convert to c long

Tags: python

Im using windows 10 to generate a security code for my DVR that i forgot the password.

Installed Python 3.7.2 on my Notebook

RAM:16GB
HDD:1TB

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from re import search
from numpy import uint32
from requests import get
from datetime import datetime

def keygen(seed):
    magic = 0
    for i, char in enumerate(seed):
        i += 1
        magic += i * ord(char) ^ i
    secret = str(uint32(1751873395 * magic))

    c = str.maketrans("012345678", "QRSqrdeyz")
    return secret.translate(c)

def get_serial_date(ip):
    try:
        req = get("http://192.168.178.43/upnpdevicedesc.xml")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Unable to connect to {ip}:\n{e}")
        sys.exit(-1)

    model = search("<modelNumber>(.*)</modelNumber>", req.text).group(1)
    serial = search("<serialNumber>(.*)</serialNumber>", req.text).group(1)
    serial = serial.replace(model, "")
    datef = datetime.strptime(req.headers["Date"], "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT")
    date = datef.strftime("%Y%m%d")

    return "{serial}{date}"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("Usage: {sys.argv[0]} <ip>")
        print("Connects to a   device and generates a security key")
        sys.exit(1)
    seed = get_serial_date(sys.argv[1])
    print("Got seed: {seed}")
    key = keygen(seed)
    print("Generated security key: {key}")
```

is there a way to fix this error code or i need to do something with my Notebook Settins?

Here is the error code that i get

```
Got seed: {seed}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "beer.py", line 41, in <module>
    key = keygen(seed)
  File "beer.py", line 14, in keygen
    secret = str(uint32(1751873395 * magic))
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to use `uint32` here: `uint32(1751873395 * magic)`? Python's native integers can, in contrast with `numpy.uint32`, be as large as your RAM allows.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `uint32` to reduce the number to the range `0 … 2**32-1`, you could use this instead:

```
secret = str((1751873395 * magic) & 0xffffffff)
```

Also note that using `enumerate` in combination with `i += 1` in the loop is very confusing.